# iOS iPad Mini / iPhone: "Unable to Install <appname> Please try again later

Tags: ios, maf

I have an .ipa file, which is the output of the deployment of my application using distribution profile.

When I try to install in any new ios device say IPad Mini(using Itunes), installation is happening till 75% after it's showing

> Unable to Install APP_NAME Please try again later.

Note: Same .ipa file used to work 4 months back, but now it's not installing.
I understand that certificates and profiles are required only for ipa deployment but installation can be done on any iOS device without much prerequisites.

Did I miss anything here or something missing like certificates/profiles in my iPad Mini?

Comment: Are the devices you are trying to install on included in the provisioning profile for the app?

Comment: you mean to say.. we need to include the device information in the provisoin profile? sorry I am new to this stuff please correct me...Do we need to install any certificates/provision profiles to device also?

Comment: In my apple account, I observed that  provisioning profile which I used for deploying the package(.ipa) is showing expired status currently .Is this causing the problem? Any dependency exists between provisional profile and my ipad mini device?

Comment: You need to ensure that the UDID of any devices that you want to install an ad-how build on are included in the provisioning profile at the time that you build the ipa. If you build for a device that is connected to your Mac then Xcode will generally take care of this for you. If you are going to distribute the ipa after building it then you will need to do this manually in the developer web site.

Comment: Actually I have one old .ipa file, but currently device UDID is not added to my  provision profile and provision profile is also expired. I need to request the admin to add my device to that list and ask to reactive the provisional profile again

Comment: mine is 3rd case(If you are going to distribute the ipa after building it then you will need to do this manually in the developer web site) ..that means I need to add that device UDID to IPhone developer website..am I correct?

Comment: Did you get solution? I am facing perfect same issue and no way to fix...

Comment: @Passionate.C: here solution is  just you need to use newly generated certificates with proper validity and generate .ipa

Answer (score 1):

I used  in-house distribution certificate which identifies team/organization within a distribution provisioning profile. when we use expired certificates, it will generate .ipa file but it won't install on IOS device.(This is the reason for my issue)

UDID of IOS device need to be added only in case of using adhoc distribution certificates to restrict the use of ipa in other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same issue.  This is how I solved it:

1) Make sure you register the UDID of your device in your Apple Developer page. This is done automatically when you build to that device with automatic signing enabled, but you could always enter the info manually.

2) In Xcode, when you export your archived project, make sure you choose **"Ad Hoc"** as method of distribution.

3) Choose your selected device under "App Thinning".  On this same screen, I unselected "Rebuild from Bitcode" because with it the build was taking forever to finish.

4) Once you generate the .ipa file, just drag and drop and it should install properly.

:)